# PHP MVC & SQL minus Model

Tags: php, sql, model-view-controller

I've been reading several articles on MVC and had a few questions I was hoping someone could possibly assist me in answering.

Firstly if **MODEL** is a representation of the data and a means in which to manipulate that data, then a Data Access Object (DAO) with a certain level of abstraction using a common interface should be sufficient for most task should it not?

To further elaborate on this point, say most of my development is done with MySQL as the underlying storage mechanism for my data, if I avoided vendor specific functions -- (i.e. UNIX_TIMESTAMP) -- in the construction of my SQL statements and used a abstract DB object that has a common interface moving between MySQL and maybe PostgreSQL, or MySQL and SQLite should be a simple process.

Here's what I'm getting at some task, are handled by a single **CONTROLLER** -- (i.e.  UserRegistration) and rather that creating a **MODEL** for that task, I can get an instance of the db object -- (i.e. DB::getInstance()) -- then make the necessary db calls to INSERT a new user. Why with such a simple task would I create a new **MODEL**?

In some of the examples I've seen a **MODEL** is created, and within that **MODEL** there's a SELECT statement that fetches x number of orders from the order table and returns an array. Why do this, if in your **CONTROLLER** your creating another loop to iterate over that array and assign it to the **VIEW**; ex. 1?

> ex. 1: `foreach ($list as $order) { $this->view->set('order', $order); }`

I guess one could modify the return so something like this is possibly; ex. 2.

> ex. 2: `while ($order = $this->model->getOrders(10)) { $this->view->set('order', $order); }`

I guess my argument is that why create a model when you can simply make the necessary db calls from within your **CONTROLLER**, assuming your using a DB object with common interface to access your data, as I suspect most of websites are using. Yes I don't expect this is practical for all task, but again when most of what's being done is simple enough to not necessarily warrant a separate **MODEL**.

As it stands right now a user makes a request 'www.mysite.com/Controller/action/args1/args2', the front controller (I call it router) passes off to Controller (class) and within that controller a certain action (method) is called and from there the appropriate **VIEW** is created and then output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I guess you're wondering whether the added complexity of a model layer -on top- of a Database Access Object is the way you want to go.  In my experience, simplicity trumps any other concern, so I would suggest that if you see a clear situation where it's simpler to completely go without a Model and have the data access occur in the equivalent of a controller, then you should go with that.

However, there are still other potential benefits to having an MVC separation:

- No SQL at all in the controller:  Maybe you decide to gather your data from a source other than a database (an array in the session? A mock object for testing? a file? just something else), or your database schema changes and you have to look for all the places that your code has to change, you could look through just the models.
- Seperation of skillsets: Maybe someone on your team is great at complex SQL queries, but not great at dealing with the php side.  Then the more separated the code is, the more people can play to their strengths (even more so when it comes to the html/css/javascript side of things).
- Conceptual object that represents a block of data:  As Steven said, there's a difference in the benefits you get from being database agnostic (so you can switch between mysql and postgresql if need be) and being **schema** agnostic (so you have an object full of data that fits together well, even if it came from different relational tables).  When you have a model that represents a good block of data, you should be able to reuse that model in more than one place (e.g. a person model could be used in logins and when displaying a personnel list).

I certainly think that the ideals of separation of the tasks of MVC are very useful.  But over time I've come to think that alternate styles, like keeping that MVC-like separation with a functional programming style, may be easier to deal with in php than a full blown OOP MVC system.

Answer (score 1):

I found this great article that addressed most of my questions. In case anyone else had similar questions or is interested in reading this article. You can find it here http://blog.astrumfutura.com/archives/373-The-M-in-MVC-Why-Models-are-Misunderstood-and-Unappreciated.html.

Answer (score 0):

The idea behind MVC is to have a clean separation between your logic. So your view is just your output, and your controller is a way of interacting with your models and using your models to get the necessary data to give to the necessary views. But all the work of actually getting data will go on your model.

If you think of your User model as an actual person and not a piece of data. If you want to know that persons name is it easier to call up a central office on the phone (the database) and request the name or to just ask the person, "what is your name?" That's one of the ideas behind the model. In a most simplistic way you can view your models as real living things and the methods you attach to them allow your controllers to ask those living things a series of questions (IE - can you view this page? are you logged in? what type of image are you? are you published? when were you last modified?). Your controller should be dumb and your model should be smart.

The other idea is to keep your SQL work in one central location, in this case your models. So that you don't have errant SQL floating around your controllers and (worst case scenario) your views.

Comment: The call to the central office will still have to occur, the only difference is it will occur in your **MODEL**. So in that sense I don't see it being easier.

I do feel some task are just so simple that to add another layer is pointless. In most of the cases I've come up on the likely hood that the DAO would change over time, was so low as to not warrant a separate **MODEL**. 

Going back and forth between **MODEL** and **CONTROLLER** to implement features, can become quite annoying. I do see a use if your working on a team and individual or group is tasked with completing different segments.